# Flutter Argument type FilePickerResult? can't be assigned to the parameter type File on FlutterInstallApkSilently package

Tags: flutter, download

Hello I making an Application which can download an apk and and make installation after download but I have this error :Argument type FilePickerResult? can't be assigned to the parameter type File

```
 FlutterInstallApkSilently.installAPK(file:file)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the filepicker result to file like this.

```
FlutterInstallApkSilently.installAPK(file:File(file.files.single.path));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got this type an error : Argument type string? can't be assigned to the Parameters type string

Comment: add ! ( not null ) after the path.